# res.sendFile does not return a HTML

Tags: angularjs, node.js

this is my code I am running the server but I can't get the page index.html
the error is

```
    app.get('/',function(request,response){
  console.log("/");
   response.sendFile(__dirname+"/views/index.html");
})
```

The error is

```
  This 127.0.0.1 page can’t be found

No webpage was found for the web address: http://127.0.0.1:5000/home
HTTP ERROR 404
```

I dont think the server is getting the `get` request. I don't see the `console.log()` getting called.

The entire code:

```
   var http = require("http");

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
// var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
// var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
// app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/"));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

app.get('/',function(request,response){
  console.log("/");
res.sendfile('views/index.html', {root: __dirname });
});


// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});
// http.createServer(function (request, response) {
//    // Send the HTTP header 
//    // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
//    // Content Type: text/plain
//    response.end('Hello World\n');
//    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
//     // Send the response body as "Hello World"


// }).listen(8081);
app.listen(5000);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:5000/');
module.exports =app;
```

Comment: does `views` contains index.html file?

Comment: @abdulbarik. yes it does..

Answer (score 2):

In your error, **`http://127.0.0.1:5000/home is not found`** that mean you did not define `/home` route. So you need to update `app.get('/')` route as following

```
app.get('/home?',function(request,response){
  console.log("Url: " + request.url);
  response.sendfile('views/index.html', {root: __dirname });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
//add your route to get file
app.get('/',function(request,response){
  console.log("/");
response.sendfile('views/index.html', {root: __dirname });
});
```

See the doc understand it correctly [res.sendFile](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile)

Hit this `URL` `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` to get your file in `browser`

Comment: Tried it..didn't work. I have a `console.log("/")` in the second line. I dont see that in the console. I dont think the server is getting the request.

Comment: Your route is not proper

Comment: I've posted it.

Comment: Show your routes/index.js file, hope it contains

Comment: I don't have any code in those files. they were generated by expess.

Comment: app.get('/',function(request,response){
  console.log("/");
response.sendfile('views/index.html', {root: __dirname });
}); 
this code in your app.js file after

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

Comment: I updated my answer add my first code in your app.js file